# How are you handle lookup tables / data with the entity framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Today i'm creating proxy entities to load the lookup data from memory.

I suggest, the entity framework should be clever enough to not generate the join to Countries / Places -table

```
DbContext.Users.Include(u => u.Country.Select(c => c.Place))
```

Instead the EF should fetch the data from memory.

How are **you** handle lookup data with the entity framework?

Comment: What is your problem? Be explicit.

Comment: If the lookup table is small, chances are it is already fetched from memory on the RDBMS side. Premature optimization is usually not a good thing, so Microsoft decided not to engage in it.

Answer (score 0):

So you want EF to eager load all lookup tables into memory before access? This sounds a bit messy and heavy handed. (what if there are updates to the lookup? How would you sync?) Joins to lookup tables are quick if youre using Pks. If you need to load the lookup tables in memory, you still need to do a join in your linq query to the proxy object holding the table data. I don't have hard data, but I can't see there being much difference in performance between the two techniques. If anything, the Linq example may be slower.

My rule of thumb is: if two techniques are similar in speed and payoff, go with the one that is less complex and easier to maintain (in your case, using the Include()).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think proxy object that load, in my case, the country and place and perhaps even the state, should be definetly faster from cache (key/value dictionary) than the join (expect the linq to entities sql generation). I think it is nonsensical to load each time the data from DB (this tables will never update at runtime). The 2nd level cache from nhibernate works yet so?

Comment: If they will never update at run time, I don't see a huge problem with caching the tables. However, I don't expect that you will see a very large performance boost, if any. Write a quick experiemental console app to measure performance of the two techniques. One that always goes to the database to join and the other that caches to start and then runs a bunch of joins. Do like 10,000 iterations of either an see if the performance boost is enough to make the architectual change. Remember - premature optimization is the root of all evil.